# Connection fails between MySQL and Spring MVC App

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have really tried to find a solution to this problem - but I can't seem to figure it out. I really hope you guys know what to do.

My Spring MVC application has begun to lose the connection to the database, and I don't know why. It is driving me crazy.

Spring DB setup:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://ip/database-name
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive=55
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxIdle=21
spring.datasource.tomcat.minIdle=13
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=55000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationInterval=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandonedTimeout=233

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I have tried to specify 'autoReconnect=true' because I found answers, that suggested that - but it hasn't solved my problem.

Error log:

```
WARN 5220 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
ERROR 5220 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The last packet successfully received from the server was 60,401,089 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 60,401,089 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection val
idity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
ERROR 5220 --- [-nio-443-exec-6] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 60,401,089 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 60,401,089 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor277.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3652) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2460) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3633) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
... 117 common frames omitted
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem, try 2 things:

1. Change `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://ip/database-name` to `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://ip/database-name?autoReconnect=true`
2. I was using c3p0 in my application, configuring idleConnectionTestPeriod and preferredTestQuery resolved my issue

   ```
   <!-- DB Configuration -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc_url}" />
     <property name="user" value="${jdbc_username}" />
     <property name="password" value="${jdbc_password}" />
     <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc_driver_class}" />

     <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
     <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" /> <!-- Determines how many connections at a time c3p0 will try to acquire when the pool is exhausted. -->
     <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc_min_pool_size}" />
     <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc_max_pool_size}" />
     <property name="maxIdleTime" value="100" /> <!-- Seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire. -->

     <!--set this value less then mysql wait_timeout -->
     <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100"/>   <!-- If this is a number greater than 0, C3P0 will test all idle, pooled but unchecked-out connections, every this number of seconds-->
     <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1"/>   <!--a query used to test connections-->
   </bean>
   ```

Your property `spring.datasource.tomcat.validationInterval` seems to do the same. From the error it seems that MySQL wait_timeout in your case is 60,401,089 ms, so the validationInterval seems less than that, but still try reducing it to 100 and see if the error reoccurs. If that doesn't work try configuring c3p0 and using the config I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try, and see if that solves it :-)